# Android- create JSON Array and JSON Object

Tags: android, json, arrays

How can I create a JSON with this format in Android:
Since the API that I will be passing will parse JsonArray then the object.
Or would it be okay if just to pass a json object? Since I will just have to insert 1 transaction per service  call.

```
{
    "student": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "John Doe",
            "year": "1st",
            "curriculum": "Arts",
            "birthday": 3/3/1995
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Michael West",
            "year": "2nd",
            "curriculum": "Economic",
            "birthday": 4/4/1994
        }
    ]
}
```

What I know is only the JSONObject.
Like this one.

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
try {
    obj.put("id", "3");
    obj.put("name", "NAME OF STUDENT");
    obj.put("year", "3rd");
    obj.put("curriculum", "Arts");
    obj.put("birthday", "5/5/1993");
} catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Any ideas. Thanks

Comment: [reference link](http://chintankhetiya.wordpress.com/2013/05/27/83/)

Comment: putting the JSONObject in a JSONArray to achieve the format posted..

Comment: Take a look at the JSONArray class http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html

Answer (score 348, accepted):

Use the following code:

```
JSONObject student1 = new JSONObject();
try {
    student1.put("id", "3");
    student1.put("name", "NAME OF STUDENT");
    student1.put("year", "3rd");
    student1.put("curriculum", "Arts");
    student1.put("birthday", "5/5/1993");

} catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

JSONObject student2 = new JSONObject();
try {
    student2.put("id", "2");
    student2.put("name", "NAME OF STUDENT2");
    student2.put("year", "4rd");
    student2.put("curriculum", "scicence");
    student2.put("birthday", "5/5/1993");

} catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}


JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

jsonArray.put(student1);
jsonArray.put(student2);

JSONObject studentsObj = new JSONObject();
    studentsObj.put("Students", jsonArray);



String jsonStr = studentsObj.toString();

    System.out.println("jsonString: "+jsonStr);
```

Comment: Perfect example!

Answer (score 33):

```
public JSONObject makJsonObject(int id[], String name[], String year[],
            String curriculum[], String birthday[], int numberof_students)
            throws JSONException {
        JSONObject obj = null;
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < numberof_students; i++) {
            obj = new JSONObject();
            try {
                obj.put("id", id[i]);
                obj.put("name", name[i]);
                obj.put("year", year[i]);
                obj.put("curriculum", curriculum[i]);
                obj.put("birthday", birthday[i]);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            jsonArray.put(obj);
        }

        JSONObject finalobject = new JSONObject();
        finalobject.put("student", jsonArray);
        return finalobject;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for this easy method.

Answer (score 5):

```
 JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
            try {
                obj.put("id", "3");
                obj.put("name", "NAME OF STUDENT");
                obj.put("year", "3rd");
                obj.put("curriculum", "Arts");
                obj.put("birthday", "5/5/1993");

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
             JSONArray js=new JSONArray(obj.toString());
             JSONObject obj2 = new JSONObject();
             obj2.put("student", js.toString());
```

Comment: i assume that 'obj' in 'JSONObject obj2 = new JSONObject();
             obj.put("student", js.toString());' is 'obj2' ?

Comment: this code throw exceptions :  org.json.JSONException: Value {"id":"3","name":"NAME OF STUDENT","year":"3rd","curriculum":"Arts","birthday":"5\/5\/1993"} of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray....It is good to test a code before posting it!

Answer (score 4):

You can create a a method and pass paramters to it and get the json as a response.

```
  private JSONObject jsonResult(String Name,int id, String curriculum) throws JSONException {
        JSONObject json = null;
        json = new JSONObject("{\"" + "Name" + "\":" + "\"" + Name+ "\""
            + "," + "\"" + "Id" + "\":" + id + "," + "\"" + "Curriculum"
            + "\":" + "\"" + curriculum+ "\"" + "}");
        return json;
      }
```

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 4):

It's too late to answer, sorry about it, for creating the below body:

```
{
    "username": "ًRajab",
    "email": "rajab.mohammadi@gmail.com",
    "phone": "+93767626554",
    "password": "123asd",
    "carType": "600fdcc646bc6409ae97e2ab",
    "fcmToken":"lljlkdsajfljasldfj;lsa",
    "profilePhoto": "https://st.depositphotos.com/2101611/3925/v/600/depositphotos_39258143-stock-illustration-businessman-avatar-profile-picture.jpg",
    "documents": {
        "DL": [
            {
                "_id": "5fccb687c5b4260011810125",
                "uriPath": "https://webfume-onionai.s3.amazonaws.com/guest/public/document/326634-beats_by_dre-wallpaper-1366x768.jpg"
            }
        ],
        "Registration": [
            {
                "_id": "5fccb687c5b4260011810125",
                "uriPath": "https://webfume-onionai.s3.amazonaws.com/guest/public/document/326634-beats_by_dre-wallpaper-1366x768.jpg"
            }
        ],
        "Insurance":[
              {
                "_id": "5fccb687c5b4260011810125",
                "uriPath": "https://webfume-onionai.s3.amazonaws.com/guest/public/document/326634-beats_by_dre-wallpaper-1366x768.jpg"
            }
        ],
         "CarInside":[
              {
                "_id": "5fccb687c5b4260011810125",
                "uriPath": "https://webfume-onionai.s3.amazonaws.com/guest/public/document/326634-beats_by_dre-wallpaper-1366x768.jpg"
            }
        ],
         "CarOutside":[
              {
                "_id": "5fccb687c5b4260011810125",
                "uriPath": "https://webfume-onionai.s3.amazonaws.com/guest/public/document/326634-beats_by_dre-wallpaper-1366x768.jpg"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

You can create dynamically like the below code:

```
JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject();
try {
    jsonBody.put("username", userName);
    jsonBody.put("email", email);
    jsonBody.put("phone", contactNumber);
    jsonBody.put("password", password);
    jsonBody.put("carType", carType);
    jsonBody.put("fcmToken", "lljlkdsajfljasldfj;lsa");
    jsonBody.put("profilePhoto", "https://st.depositphotos.com/2101611/3925/v/600/depositphotos_39258143-stock-illustration-businessman-avatar-profile-picture.jpg");

    JSONObject document = new JSONObject();

    try {
        document.put("DL", createDocument("5fccb687c5b4260011810125", "https://st.depositphotos.com/2101611/3925/v/600/depositphotos_39258143-stock-illustration-businessman-avatar-profile-picture.jpg"));
        document.put("Registration", createDocument("5fccb687c5b4260011810125", "https://st.depositphotos.com/2101611/3925/v/600/depositphotos_39258143-stock-illustration-businessman-avatar-profile-picture.jpg"));
        document.put("Insurance", createDocument("5fccb687c5b4260011810125", "https://st.depositphotos.com/2101611/3925/v/600/depositphotos_39258143-stock-illustration-businessman-avatar-profile-picture.jpg"));
        document.put("CarInside", createDocument("5fccb687c5b4260011810125", "https://st.depositphotos.com/2101611/3925/v/600/depositphotos_39258143-stock-illustration-businessman-avatar-profile-picture.jpg"));
        document.put("CarOutside", createDocument("5fccb687c5b4260011810125", "https://st.depositphotos.com/2101611/3925/v/600/depositphotos_39258143-stock-illustration-businessman-avatar-profile-picture.jpg"));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    jsonBody.put("documents", document.toString());

    Log.i("MAHDI", "Hello: Mahdi: Data: " + jsonBody);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And the createDocument method code:

```
public JSONArray createDocument(String id, String imageUrl) {

    JSONObject dlObject = new JSONObject();
    try {
        dlObject.put("_id", id);
        dlObject.put("uriPath", imageUrl);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    JSONArray dlArray = new JSONArray();
    dlArray.put(dlObject);

    return dlArray;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simpler (but not so short) version which doesn't require try-catch:

```
Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();
data.put("user", "mark@facebook.com");
data.put("pass", "123");

JSONObject jsonData = new JSONObject(data);
```

If you want to add a jsonObject into a field, you can do this way:

```
data.put("socialMedia", (new JSONObject()).put("facebookId", "1174989895893400"));
data.put("socialMedia", (new JSONObject()).put("googleId", "106585039098745627377"));
```

Unfortunately it needs a try-catch because of the put() method.

**IF** you want to avoid try-catch again (not very recommended, but it's ok if you can guarantee well formated json strings), you might do this way:

```
data.put("socialMedia", "{ 'facebookId': '1174989895893400' }");
```

You can do the same about JsonArrays and so on.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Have been struggling with this till I found out the answer:

1. Use GSON library:

   ```
   Gson gson = Gson();
   String str_json = gson.tojson(jsonArray);`
   ```
2. Pass the json array. This will be auto stringfied. This option worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
JSONObject jsonResult = new JSONObject();
try {
  jsonResult.put("clave", "valor");
  jsonResult.put("username", "iesous");
  jsonResult.put("password", "1234");

} catch (JSONException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
 e.printStackTrace();
}

Log.d("DEV","jsonResult->"+jsonResult);
```

Comment: You should add some narrative to explain your answer and improve the formatting.

Answer (score 0):

```
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

            //** Temp array
            List<String[]> tmpArray = new ArrayList<>();
            tmpArray.add(new String[]{"b001","book1"}); 
            tmpArray.add(new String[]{"b002","book2"}); 

            //** Json Array Example
            JSONArray jrrM = new JSONArray();
            for(int i=0; i<tmpArray.size(); i++){
                JSONArray jrr = new JSONArray();
                jrr.put(tmpArray.get(i)[0]);
                jrr.put(tmpArray.get(i)[1]);
                jrrM.put(jrr);
            }

           //Json Object Example
           JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
            try {
                jsonObj.put("plno","000000001");                   
                jsonObj.put("rows", jrrM);

            }catch (JSONException ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }   


            // Bundles them
            params.put("user", "guest");
            params.put("tb", "book_store");
            params.put("action","save");
            params.put("data", jsonObj.toString());

           // Now you can send them to the server.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  public void DataSendReg(String picPath, final String ed2, String ed4, int bty1, String bdatee, String ed1, String cno, String address , String select_item, String select_item1, String height, String weight) {

      final ProgressDialog dialog=new ProgressDialog(SignInAct.this);
      dialog.setMessage("Process....");
      AsyncHttpClient httpClient=new AsyncHttpClient();
      RequestParams params=new RequestParams();
      File pic = new File(picPath);
      try {
          params.put("image",pic);
      } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
      params.put("height",height);
      params.put("weight",weight);
      params.put("pincode",select_item1);
      params.put("area",select_item);
      params.put("address",address);
      params.put("contactno",cno);
      params.put("username",ed1);
      params.put("email",ed2);
      params.put("pass",ed4);
      params.put("bid",bty1);
      params.put("birthdate",bdatee);
      params.put("city","Surat");
      params.put("state","Gujarat");


      httpClient.post(WebAPI.REGAPI,params,new JsonHttpResponseHandler(){
          @Override
          public void onStart() {
              dialog.show();
          }

          @Override
          public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
              try {
                  String done=response.get("msg").toString();
                  if(done.equals("s")) {
                      Toast.makeText(SignInAct.this, "Registration Success Fully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      DataPrefrenceMaster.SetRing(ed2);
                      startActivity(new Intent(SignInAct.this, LoginAct.class));
                      finish();
                  }
                  else  if(done.equals("ex")) {
                      Toast.makeText(SignInAct.this, "email already exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  }else Toast.makeText(SignInAct.this, "Registration failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              } catch (JSONException e) {
                  Toast.makeText(SignInAct.this, "e :: ="+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              }
          }

          @Override
          public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, Throwable throwable, JSONObject errorResponse) {
              Toast.makeText(SignInAct.this, "Server not Responce", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              Log.d("jkl","error");
          }

          @Override
          public void onFinish() {
                   dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: It would help to add some context explanation with your code as it seems you're answering the wrong question...

Answer (score -2):

You should use JSONObject.put method

https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#put(java.lang.String,%20double)