# Create JSON Object with Json Array in Android

Tags: android, json

```
       "ORDERDETAIL":[
            {
                "Description":"asdf",
                "Quantity":"5",
                "Unit Price":"77",
                "No.":"1",
                "Line No.":"100",
                "Document Type":"1",
                "Document No.":"109"
            },
            {
                "Description":"torage",
                "Quantity":"5",
                "Unit Price":"7",
                "No.":"19",
                "Line No.":"10",
                "Document Type":"1",
                "Document No.":"10"
            },
            {
                "Description":"IN",
                "Quantity":"5",
                "Unit Price":"7",
                "No.":"1",
                "Line No.":"1",
                "Document Type":"1",
                "Document No.":"9"
            }
        ]
```

Code Part:

```
ArrayList<String> arlstKeyDetail = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> arlstValDetail = new ArrayList<String>();

JSONArray jsonSubDataArry = new JSONArray();
JSONObject jsonSubObj = new JSONObject();
JSONObject jsonTemp1 = new JSONObject();

Iterator iterKey = jsonArrDisplayRecord.getJSONObject(1).keys();
            while(iterKey.hasNext())
            {
                String key = (String)iterKey.next();
                arlstKeyDetail.add(key);
                arlstValDetail.add(jsonArrDisplayRecord.getJSONObject(1).getString(key));


            }

for(int i=0 ; i < arlstKeyDetail.size() ; i++)
            {
                for(int j=0; j <itLength; j++){
                    jsonSubObj.put(arlstKeyDetail.get(j), arlstValDetail.get(j));
                }
                jsonSubDataArry.put(jsonSubObj);
                jsonTemp1.put("ORDERDETAIL", jsonSubDataArry);
            }
```

I want to create Json Object with Json Array like above format in android. i already tried lots of thing but didnt get as like above.

Comment: What did you tried? add those codes

Comment: @Pankaj check it above..

Comment: u mean u want the above json as json object? like { and ur contents above} ?

Comment: @Monica yes, i want to create json like that..

Comment: @Monica, no actually i have already jsonarray but i did some operations for remove some values from that. so, now after removing i want make again jsonarray.

Comment: JSONObject JSONSend = new JSONObject();
 JSONSend.put("Items", mJSONArray);

Comment: i think obove code does that

Comment: dont loop it directly put it as shown in above code in my comment

Comment: No, it will not work like that. because i have keys and values which can be convert into jsonobject and then jsonarray. @Monica

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17810270/1168654

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the code [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/). This has the same example that you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONObject ORDERDETAIL = new JSONObject();

JSONArray array = new JSONArray();

JSONObject array_content1 = new JSONObject();
array_content1.put("Description","asdf");
array_content1.put("Quantity","5");
.....

JSONObject array_content2 = new JSONObject();
array_content1.put("Description","torage");
array_content1.put("Quantity","5");
.....

array.add(array_content1);
array.add(array_content2);

ORDERDETAIL.put("ORDERDETAIL",array);
```

This is your  format