# How to create JSONObject in Android?

Tags: android, arrays, json

I am working with web services. I want to create a JSONObject and send the values through web service. How to do it?

```
 String redeem = edit_messageredeem.getText().toString();
                     HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                     String httppostURL = "http:// ...";
                        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(httppostURL);
                        Log.v(TAG, "postURL: " + httppost);   

                               List<NameValuePair> data2 = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(5);
                               data2.add(new BasicNameValuePair("merchant_id", "02"));
                               data2.add(new BasicNameValuePair("merchant_location_id", "03"));
                               data2.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user_id", "04"));
                               data2.add(new BasicNameValuePair("merchant_kiosk_id", "04"));
                               data2.add(new BasicNameValuePair("coupon_code", redeem));
                               httppost.setHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,"application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
                               httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(data2 , "UTF-8"));               
                    //         httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(data));
                    //         httpclient.execute(httppost);                 
                               HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                               HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();  
                               if (resEntity != null) {                               
                                   String responseStr = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity).trim();
                                   Log.v(TAG, "Response: " +  responseStr);
                                   Log.i("TAG",""+response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
                                   Toast.makeText(RedeemActivity.this,  responseStr, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
                                   // you can add an if statement here and do other actions based on the response
                               }               
                               edit_messageredeem.setText(""); //reset the message text field
                         //      Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Sent",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                               Toast.makeText(RedeemActivity.this, "Data: " +data2,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (Throwable t) {
                            Toast.makeText(RedeemActivity.this, "Request failed: " + t.toString(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                }
}
```

Comment: before asking others for code please try first and make sure you read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: you must be using print_r in php instead of json_encode for your data array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating json object

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
```

adding values into json object

```
obj.put("key", "your_value");
```

please see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17810270/3442067)

**EDITED**

This may be help you

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
array.put(obj);
JSONObject par_obj= new JSONObject();
par_obj.put("data",array);
```

Comment: The following is what I am getting as output.
    Array
     (
     [merchant_id] => 02
     [merchant_location_id] => 03
     [user_id] => 04
     [merchant_kiosk_id] => 04
     [subscriber_phone] => 999-999-9999
     )

    But instead of this I want the output as follows:
    {
        "data": [
            {     
                [merchant_id] => 02
                [merchant_location_id] => 03
                [user_id] => 04
                [merchant_kiosk_id] => 04
                [subscriber_phone] => 999-999-9999  
            }
         ]
     }

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convet any object to JSONObcjet Download GSON jar then convert like

```
Gson gson=new Gson();
gson.toJson(Your object that which you want to convert);
```

I hope this one will help to you :)

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/downloads/detail?name=google-gson-2.2.4-release.zip& here it says it is deprecated. Actually I am supposed to create json array and send it through post. I tried a lot but couldn't make it work.

Comment: I don't know why they are puting like deprecated.but It's still working.just use this.surely this one help to you :)

Comment: The following is what I am getting as output. Array ( [merchant_id] => 02 [merchant_location_id] => 03 [user_id] => 04 [merchant_kiosk_id] => 04 [subscriber_phone] => 999-999-9999 ) But instead of this I want the output as follows: { "data": [ { [merchant_id] => 02 [merchant_location_id] => 03 [user_id] => 04 [merchant_kiosk_id] => 04 [subscriber_phone] => 999-999-9999 } ] }

Comment: you are getting single data.you should add within array.For ex:  `List<Your Data Class> data=new ArrayList<Your Data Class>(); `  and add your result within data. then convert that data as jsonObject.like   `gson.toJson(data);`

Answer (score 0):

Here my server side code:

```
@Path("chat")
public class Chat {

Statement statement;
Gson gson=new Gson();



@Path("/getPrevious")
@GET
public String getPreviousChat(@QueryParam("senderId")String senderId,
                @QueryParam("receiverId")String receiverId){

    ChatDataList list=new ChatDataList();
    ArrayList<ChatData> datas=new ArrayList<ChatData>();

    try {
        statement=DBConn.getConnection();
        ResultSet rs=statement.executeQuery("select * from chat where sender_id="+senderId
                +" AND receiver_id="+receiverId+" ORDER BY id DESC limit 50");
        while (rs.next()) {
            ChatData data=new ChatData();
            data.setSenderId(rs.getInt("sender_id"));
            data.setReceiverId(rs.getInt("receiver_id"));
            data.setMsg(rs.getString("msg"));
            datas.add(data);
        }
        list.setChatList(datas);

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return gson.toJson(list);
}
```

}

Here I getting value from dataBase and send JSON as String.It working awesome to me.Just check this :)

Answer (score 0):

you are getting single data.you should add within array.For ex:

```
List<Your Data Class> data=new ArrayList<Your Data Class>();
```

and add your result within data. then convert that data as jsonObject.like

`Gson gson=new Gson();
 gson.toJson(data);`

It will print like your expectation :)

Comment: how to add result within data? I am getting error. Thanks bdw for your help.

Comment: I have done this: 
                            
                            String[] mStringArray = new String[data.size()];
                            mStringArray = data.toArray(mStringArray);
                            for(int i = 0; i < mStringArray.length ; i++){
                                Log.d("string is",(mStringArray[i]));}

Comment: you have to use pojo class within list.just search how to use POJO class :)

Comment: Thanks a ton. It worked! :) I did: List <NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList <NameValuePair>();
nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data", data1.toString()));
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, HTTP.UTF_8));