# How to Create Json with array list Android?

Tags: android, json, wcf, post, arraylist

i need to create JSON and set array list on a field. 
We have api of C#,.NET and they want me to send a JSON.

They want these parameters to be used:

"CustomerID": 1,
"AddressID": 1,
"Array": arraylist

how can i do that ?

Comment: check it once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17810044/android-create-json-array-and-json-object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Google's Json library called [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) for serialization and deserialization.

I am assuming you are using Android Studio, if not you can still import this library to your project.
First, add this line to your module's build.gradle file's dependencies:

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
```

Then create a class, add your variables and tag them for JSON:

```
public class ToJson {

    @SerializedName("CustomerID")
    public int CustomerId;

    @SerializedName("AddressID")
    public int AddressId;

    @SerializedName("Array")
    public List array;
}
```

Create an object and populate:

```
ToJson toJson = new ToJson();
toJson.CustomerId = 1;
toJson.AddressId = 1;
toJson.array = new ArrayList<>();
toJson.array.add("Item 1");
toJson.array.add("Item 2");
toJson.array.add("Item 3");
```

Then create a Gson object and use it for serialization:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String JSON = gson.toJson(toJson);
```

The output JSON string is:

```
{
  "Array": [
    "Item 1",
    "Item 2",
    "Item 3"
  ],
  "CustomerID": 1,
  "AddressID": 1
}
```

This is simple as that.
You can also check [Gson User Guide](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide) for further information about serialization/deserialization.

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend using Jackson.

You only need to implement a POJO and annotate it.

Check this out. http://www.studytrails.com/java/json/java-jackson-Serialization-list.jsp