# Send List Objects using Intent from one Activity to another using Parcelable | Android

Tags: java, android, android-intent, parcelable

I have  Arraylist `private ArrayList<Movies> mMovies;`  of type Movies which is implemented as `Parcelable` defined in `MainActivity`.

`mMovies` contains list of movies around 20.

within `MainActivity` inside `onCreateView()` method
I tried to pass the parcelable objects to another Activity called `DetailActivity`

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DetailActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("MOVIES", movieList);
                        startActivity(intent);
```

Using debugger i can see the `movieList` contains 20 rows.

This is how i tried to read parcelable objects which was passed through intents from MainActivity.

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Bundle bundle = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();
        mMovies = getActivity().getIntent().getParcelableExtra("MOVIES");
    }
```

While i try to see the `mMovies` value using debugger it shows `null`

[image]

Comment: Are you sure your `Parcelable` implementation is correct?

Comment: I think its correct.
You can see it here: https://gist.github.com/GPandey515/708ccd75327e6131ddc0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `putParcelable("MOVIES",mMovies);` and `getParcelableArrayListExtra("MOVIES")` instead. [How can I make my custom objects Parcelable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7181526/how-can-i-make-my-custom-objects-be-parcelable]) may provide some more insight.

Answer (score 1):

First, you put to extras list, but trying to get a Movie onject, use `getParcelableArrayList()`

Second, check out Parcelable implementation (and make sure you call right consctructor in CREATOR)

Answer (score -1):

My suggestion is exporting the Movies class to Json String as in: [Android- create JSON Array and JSON Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17810044/android-create-json-array-and-json-object)
Then, passing it as String from one Intent to the second

Comment: How do you suggest OP serializes the `Movies` class to JSON?

Comment: My suggestion is exporting the Movies class to Json String as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17810044/android-create-json-array-and-json-object Then, passing it as String from one Intent to the second