# Making JSON in android

Tags: android, json

I need to make JSON like this on android -

```
{
    "Warp":[
        {
            "Type":"Cotton",
            "Property":"Carded",
            "Count":"10"
        },
        {
            "Type":"Cotton",
            "Property":"Carded",
            "Count":"10"
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried

```
j = new JSONObject();

j2.put("Type", "Cotton");
j2.put("Property", "Carded");
j2.put("Count", "10");

a = new JSONArray();
a.put("Warp", j2);
```

But looks like I cannot directly put an JSONArray inside a JSONObject like this.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You have a `Object` -> `Array` -> `Object`

Comment: Try this if you find your solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17810044/android-create-json-array-and-json-object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
// Create object
JSONObject objectInArray = new JSONObject();
objectInArray.put("Type", "Cotton");
objectInArray.put("Property", "Carded");
objectInArray.put("Count", "10");

// Create array and add the object
JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
array.put(objectInArray);

// Create the object and add the array on "wrap"
JSONObject wrapObject = new JSONObject();
wrapObject.put("wrap", array);
```

Answer (score 1):

Do Something like this :

```
try {
                JSONObject mainObject = new JSONObject();
                JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
                JSONObject object1 = new JSONObject();
                JSONObject object2 = new JSONObject();
                object1.put("Type", "Cotton");
                object1.put("Property", "Carded");
                object1.put("Count", "10");
                object2.put("Type", "Cotton");
                object2.put("Property", "Carded");
                object2.put("Count", "10");
                array.put(object1);
                array.put(object2);
                mainObject.put("Warp", array);
            } catch (JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
j = new JSONObject();

            j2.put("Type", "Cotton");
            j2.put("Property", "Carded");
            j2.put("Count", "10");


            a = new JSONArray();
            a.put(j2);

    j.put(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

you cannot put `JsonObject` with `key` inside `JsonArray`, `JsonArray` will hold all JsonObject without key.

```
JSONArray warpArray=new JSONArray();
JSONObject inner=new JSONObject();
inner.put("Type", "Cotton");
inner.put("Property", "Carded");
inner.put("Count", "10");
warpArray.put(inner);

JSONObject mainJson=new JSONObject();
mainJson.put("Warp",warpArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public JSONObject createGroupInServer() throws JSONException {

        JSONObject jResult = new JSONObject();


        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < ArrayList.size(); i++) {
            JSONObject jGroup = new JSONObject();
            jGroup .put("Type", "Cotton");
            jGroup .put("Property", "Carded");
            jGroup .put("Count", "10");

            jArray.put(jGroup);
        }

    jResult.put("Warp", jArray);
    return jResult;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use easily like this

```
try {
        JSONObject root = new JSONObject();

        JSONArray wrap = new JSONArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            JSONObject wrapObj = new JSONObject();
            wrapObj.put("Count", "10");
            wrapObj.put("Property", "Carded");
            wrapObj.put("Type", "Cotton");
            wrap.put(wrapObj);
        }
        root.put("Warp", wrap);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Don't forgot to put your code in **try-catch** block.