# Android String to JSON Array Error

Tags: android, json

I am parse json string in URL.

```
TextView tv3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv3);
TextView tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv2);
TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);

String str = "[{\"ID\":\"1\",\"lat\":\"40.7646815\",\"lon\":\"29.030855\"},{\"ID\":\"2\",\"lat\":\"41.10812\",\"lon\":\"29.030855\"}]";


JSONArray jsonarray = null;
try {

    jsonarray = new JSONArray(str);
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject obj = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);

        String lat = obj.getString("lat");
        String lon = obj.getString("lon");
        String id = obj.getString("ID");

        tv3.setText(lat);
        tv2.setText(lon);
        tv1.setText(ID);
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I want converting `JSONArray` to `String` **but JSONArray returning empty.**
Where I'm Error ? Thank You..

Comment: @prudhvi do you not know how to escape quotes in java strings?

Comment: any exception at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
jsonarray = new JSONArray(str.replace("\\\"", "\"").replace("\n","").replaceAll("^\"|\"$", "").trim());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use JSONObject and JSONArray classes to construct JSONArray, instead of writing it as a String.

Refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/17810270/4586742

Comment: The JSON string is coming from a URL, if I understand the question correctly.

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
JSONArray arrayObj = null;
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
object = jsonParser.parse(str);
arrayObj = (JSONArray) object;
```

Comment: where is this `JSONParser` class coming from?