# How to send data message without using Firebase console

Tags: android, firebase

I am developing post and comment app, where one user can post some question, and any other use can answer on that post. but when any user comments on a post a user who post the question should receive notification. Suppose User (A) posted some question and User (B) answer on that. then user A should notify that somebody answers on your post and after clicking on a notification a particular post should open.
Help me to sort the problem thankyou in advance :)

Comment: Best option for you will be to cloud functions with a database trigger. With this, whenever someone replies to a post, you can use the admin api to send a notification to the related user which you can easily get using the same admin api.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to read [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message)?

All you need is to send POST request to

```
https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/myproject-b5ae1/messages:send HTTP/1.1
```

With message

```
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer ya29.ElqKBGN2Ri_Uz...HnS_uNreA

{
  "message":{
    "token" : "bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
    "notification" : {
      "body" : "This is an FCM notification message!",
      "title" : "FCM Message",
      }
   }
}
```

For sending message to exact user you can create new unique topic or write correct `to` parameter. For example:

```
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:key=AIzaSyZ-1u...0GBYzPu7Udno5aA

{ "data": {
    "score": "5x1",
    "time": "15:10"
  },
  "to" : "bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1..."
}
```

Comment: can you explain me this code that how and where to implement this code >

Comment: @NabeelNazir emm, do you know how to send post requests?

Comment: Actually No  ! :(

Comment: can you refer me any reference video tutorial ?

Comment: @NabeelNazir assuming search does not work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938502/sending-post-data-in-android   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17810044/android-create-json-array-and-json-object

Comment: @NabeelNazir if you read examples probably you should write another question about http requests/json/etc

Comment: Which token need to be use for  'Bearer ya29.ElqKBGN2Ri_Uz...HnS_uNreA' this ?, I use idToken which is return by firebase authtication .  did not work