# Create json array format in android

Tags: android, json, arraylist

I want to create json request string. How can I do that? This is my following array:

```
[1,2,3,4,5];
```

Now I want to create this type of json request:

```
{
    "contact_approve":[
    {
    "contact_id":1    
    },
    {
    "contact_id":2    
    },
    {
    "contact_id":3    
    },
    {
    "contact_id":4    
    },
    {
    "contact_id":5    
    },
    ]

}
```

Does anyone has the idea about how to create this type of json string?

Comment: There is this thing called Google and I am pretty sure it will give you answers/directions to go... just try it first

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17810044/android-create-json-array-and-json-object

Comment: create Json object and put your keys in it with for loop, use something called Google

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is code:

```
  try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
        int[] dataArray = {1,2,3,4,5};
        for( int i=0;i<dataArray.length;i++) {
            JSONObject internalObject = new JSONObject();
            internalObject.put("contact_id",dataArray[i]);
            array.put(internalObject);

        }
        jsonObject.put("contact_approve", array);

        System.out.print(jsonObject);
        Log.v("JsonObject",jsonObject.toString());
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well it's simple you can use Gson library to convert objects to json like below;

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson({your object you want to convert to json});
```

Another thing to mention is if you are sending request to server you don't even need to do json serialization on your own, Use Retrofit and it will do this for you.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through the array and print the relevant string for each element.

```
public static String ConvertToContactJson(int [] array)
{
    String finalstr = "{\"contact_approve\":[";

    for (int i=0; i< array.length; i++)
    {
        finalstr += "{\"contact_id\":"+array[i]+"}";

        if (i < array.length-1) finalstr += ",";
    }

    finalstr += "]}";

    return finalstr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Try This

```
try{

JSONArray jarray=new JSonArray();

for(int i=0;i<array.size();i++){

JSONObject j=new JSONObject();
j.put("contact_id",array[i]);

jarray.put(j);

}
}catch(Exception e){

e.printStackStrace();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**JSONObject** which start with {} 
**JSONArray**  which start with [] 
In your case you have a JSONObject which has an JSONArray.

let me give you an example.

```
  public void createJson() throws JSONException {
    // Create main JSON object
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

    //Create an JSON ARRAY which will have a key "contact_approve" later on
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

    Integer contacts[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length ; i++) {
        JSONObject contactID = new JSONObject();
        jsonArray.put(contactID.put("contact_id", i));
    }

    jsonObject.put("contact_approve", jsonArray);

    String json = jsonObject.toString();
    Log.d("JSON", json);
}
```

Incase if you  need to Parse the JSON response, have a look at Moshi and GSON libraries which make your day better. These libraries can Parse JAVA classes in to JSON. 
I use [https://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer] to view or minify the json.

Good luck.