# merging multiple JSON objects in an existing JSON array

Tags: android, json, android-json

I have a jsonarray like below:

```
 [
   {
      "WarrantyGuarantee":{
         "Row Id":"RA048",
         "QuestionKey":"WarrantyGuarantee",
         "Answer":"Y"
      }
   },
   {
      "RewardLoyalty":{
         "Row Id":"RA051",
         "QuestionKey":"RewardLoyalty",
         "Answer":"Y"
      }
   },
   {
      "WarrantyGuarantee":{
         "Row Id":"RA048",
         "QuestionKey":"WarrantyGuarantee",
         "Answer":"Y"
      }
   },
   {
      "RewardLoyalty":{
         "Row Id":"RA051",
         "QuestionKey":"RewardLoyalty",
         "Answer":"Y"
      }
   },
   {
      "MinCost":{
         "Row Id":"RA044",
         "QuestionKey":"MinCost",
         "Answer":"hgf"
      }
   }
]
```

I also have multiple json objects:

```
  {
   "RA048":"Y",
   "RA051":"Y"
  }
```

and

```
 {
   "RA049":"Y",
   "RA051":"N"
 }
```

I want to merge all my json objects in the jsonarray from the above.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17810044/android-create-json-array-and-json-object

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();
JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
jo.put("key",(Object)array);
```

Use this method.