# Insert object to array json data

Tags: java, android, json

I need a help.

I have JSON with data:

```
{
   "Tomy":[
   {
      "name":"Tomy",
      "age":25
   }]
}
```

In my app, I need to add new persons and save to JSON.

How do I need to insert a new person to the last position in JSON?

Example what I want to get::

```
{
   "Tomy":[
   {
      "name":"Tomy",
      "age":25
   }],
   "Boby":[
   {
      "name":"Boby",
      "age:38
   }]
}
```

Please help explain how to work with JSON. Or indicate the direction.

Comment: why is `"Tomy":[` an array?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android- create JSON Array and JSON Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17810044/android-create-json-array-and-json-object)

Comment: *Example what I want to get:* - you want invalid Json?

Comment: Thanks for the help and the one who put me dislike. Can't you see that I'm new here?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow Vlad! Please take some time to read [How to ask good questions?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Also please try to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your own attempt and show it to us.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a person which will be array of individual person objects, something like this below.

```
{
   "persons":[
   {
      "name":"Tomy",
      "age":25
   },
   {
      "name":"Boby",
      "age:38
   }]
}
```

`public class MyJson{ private List<Person> persons; //its getter setter}`
and then Person class
`public class Person{ private String name; private int age; //its getter setter}`

then code to add it into json like below

```
List<Persons> personLs = Lists.newArrayList();
```

personLs.add();

and then
JsonUtils.getMapper().writeValueAsString(new MyJson(personLs));

Comment: Thanks. Structure of data I unintended. But I can't to insert new person to json. I need to get size of jsonArray of Person, and after to insert only?

Comment: Ok, so you will create a Person class, like below